# BAT file - Create empty unicode encoded file

Tags: batch-file

I just want a BAT script that creates an empty text file in unicode format when ran. This is what I have so far

```
@echo off
echo.>"file.txt"
CMD /U /C Type file.txt >> unicode.txt
```

It works, but its messy as it creates two files. Any simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about directly

```
CMD /U /C echo.> unicode.txt
```

?